# Trying to make a reusable function and display the result in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function that I am trying to work with. All I am trying to do is to get the values of days, hours, min and sec into the .overTime div. I want to use the same function over and over again because i have more divs in which I want to display the same values but in a diff manner.

You guys are awesome Thank You.

```
    NowTime = new Date(); //Time Now
StartTime = new Date($('#StartTime').val());
StopTime = new Date($('#StopTime').val());

function fixIntegers(integer){
    if (integer < 0)
        integer = 0;
    if (integer < 10)
        return '0' + integer;
    return '' + integer;
}  
    function Test( difference )
    {
        var toReturn = { days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0 };
        toReturn.seconds = fixIntegers(difference % 60);
        difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);    

        toReturn.minutes = fixIntegers(difference % 60);
        difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);

        toReturn.hours = fixIntegers(difference % 24);
        difference = Math.floor(difference / 24);

        toReturn.days = fixIntegers(difference);
        return toReturn;
    }

    function run()
    {
        var output = Test( Math.floor( ( NowTime - StopTime ) / 1000 ) );
        $('.OverTime').html( output.days + ':' + output.hours + ':' + output.minutes + ':' + seconds);
    }
setInterval(run, 1000)
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/8943U/47/

Comment: Where are you calling the function ? And be more specific about the problem you are facing

Comment: You are trying to do invalid math on a date object. try `alert(NowTime);` to see what the object you are working with evaluates to.

Comment: @JRulle Sir/Madam: I know what NowTime alerts, and it is not "invalid math". Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is this:

```
$('.OverTime').html( output.days + ':' + output.hours + ':' + output.minutes + ':' + seconds);
```

Should be:

```
$('.OverTime').html( output.days + ':' + output.hours + ':' + output.minutes + ':' + output.seconds);
```

The variable `seconds` does not exist, you need `output.seconds` instead. Then your function will begin to work [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/8943U/50/).

Your second problem is that those values are NaN, I'll leave it to you to solve that one.

Cheers!

Comment: If you can't figure out why they are NaN, let me know and I will help you.